# Echo Same Item Once In loop and echo unique or order Items once

Tags: php, mysqli

I am a beginner in PHP so please bear with my me.

My Current Situation is that I am having issues printing orders takes a lot of paper for our restaurant.

The Print out looks like this:

```
Receipt #: 0000
Cashier: Name here
Table #: table name
Client #: ID here
Date: 2017-03-11 8:26 PM
QTY: 4
Order:
Item 1
----------------------------------
Receipt #: 0000
Cashier: Name here
Table #: table name
Client #: ID here
Date: 2017-03-11 8:26 PM
QTY: 1
Order:
Item 2
```

I generally want to print it this way to save paper

```
Receipt #: 0000

Table #: table name
Client #: ID here
Date: 2017-03-11 8:26 PM
Cashier: Name here
QTY: 4
Order:
Item 1
Notes:

Cashier: Name here
QTY: 1
Order: 
Item 2
Notes:
```

My current Query and Echo is this:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM orders  WHERE  catid = 'Drinks' and printed = 'ticket' and status = 'active' and groupid = '".$_GET['groupid']."' and tid NOT LIKE 'Upstairs%'  Order By  oid asc ";

 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $oid = $row{'oid'};
 $product = $row['pname'];
 $groupidx = $row['groupid'];
 $printreceipt = $row['printreceipt'];
 ?>

 <h4 class="printableArea" style="line-height:20px;font-size:15px; margin:0px  0px 0px 5px; color: <?php echo $color;?>;   font-family: Courier New "><hr  style="margin:0px;"/><span style="font-weight:900;"> Receipt #: <?php  $newinfo =     $row{'info'}; echo $row{'info'}; ?> <br> Cashier: <?php echo $row['user'];?><br>       Table #:
 <?php  echo $row['tid']; ?> <br> Client #: <?php  echo $row['cid']; ?> <br> Date:      <?php echo date('Y-m-d h:i A', strtotime($row['date']))?><br> QTY: <?php  echo $row['qty']; ?> <br>Order:<br> <?php if($row['viet']==""){ echo $product;}else{ echo $row['viet']; } ?  > <br> <?php  echo $row['attr']; ?> <br> Notes: <br> <?php  echo    $row['extraoptions']; ?></span></h4>

 <?php
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }
  $sql2 = "UPDATE orders SET printed='Yes' WHERE catid = 'Drinks' and oid = '$oid'           and (status <> 'waiting' and status <> 'deleted')";
      if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
    //   echo "Record updated successfully";
      ?>

    <script>
 <?php
 if(!empty($printreceipt)){
 $printreceipt = $printreceipt;
 }else {$printreceipt='Bar';}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to split the span's output so that a 'header' would only be printed once. Here's one way to accomplish the task:

I was not sure what to do with this portion, so I left it out of my example. Also, it was not clear how 'Item' was used? There was no matching label in the code.

```
<?php  echo $row['attr']; ?> <br>
```

You will likely need to 'tweak' the desired output to your liking, since I'm simply reusing your info in the example below.

First, up before the while loop, add this variable:

```
$showHeader = true;
while(($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Then I split the span text to use that variable that should show a header once (receipt to date), then all the other data (cashier to notes -- except for Item, which I noted above) should display as trailing rows below the header.

```
<h4 class="printableArea" style="line-height:20px;font-size:15px; margin:0px 0px 0px 5px; color: <?php echo $color;?>; font-family: Courier New "><hr  style="margin:0px;"/>
<span style="font-weight:900;">

<?php
if ( true === $showHeader ) { // to achieve a 'single header'
   $showHeader = false; // avoid other headers
   echo 'Receipt #: ' . $row['info'] . '<br><br>'; 
   echo 'Table #: ' . $row['tid'] . '<br>';
   echo 'Client #: ' . $row['cid'] . '<br>';
   echo 'Date: ' . date('Y-m-d h:i A', strtotime($row['date'])) . '<br>';
}

echo 'Cashier: ' . $row['user'] . '<br>';
echo 'QTY: ' . $row['qty'] . '<br>';
echo 'Order: ' . '<br>';
    if ( $row['viet']=="") {
        echo $product;
    }
    else {
        echo $row['viet'];
    }
echo '<br>' . 'Notes:' . '<br>' . $row['extraoptions'];
?>
</span></h4>
```

That is the general idea. If any clarification may be needed, please add a comment.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Tested your code now what's happening is that its print it 2x in the same format as before in which i also need to print the tickets 2x.

Comment: Still using the old format with duplicate headers but now prints it 2x would it be possible to print it 2x as well with a note stating original then copy for the 2nd copy?

Comment: was able to make your code work by putting the items before the while statement. my problem now is that its printing x number of times based on items . eg if i have 2 menu items it prints 2x if i have 3 or more it prints 4.

Here is the updated post and code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43254650/php-while-loop-issue-causing-print-issue-and-need-to-print-2x?noredirect=1#comment73577955_43254650